# JMeter - How to verify that particular elements of response json are present

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a REST request that have a response similar to:
    {"names": ["Peter","John","Lily","Maria"]}
I need an assertation  that verifies the number of elements is at least 3 (true in the case above, because there are total of 4 elements) and that the elements - "John" amnd "Maria" are present (I don't care for the other values).
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def names = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).names

   if (names.size() < 3 || !names.contains('John') || !names.contains('Maria')) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
   }
   ```

The assertion will fail the sampler if array size will be less than 3 or won't contain the mentioned names.

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSON path assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=JSONPathAssertion). For assertion that John is "present" set it up like this

[image: JSON path assertion for names]

To assert exact count use it like this

[image: JSON path assertion for count]

---

However you have to use exact count of names. So better option could be to use JSR223 Assertion. You can choose to use Javascript as language with this code:

```
    json_body = JSON.parse(SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString());
    log.info("Finding JSON in response data: "+json_body);
    number_of_names=json_body.names.length;
    if(number_of_names<=3) {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
        AssertionResult.setError(true);
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Failed to match number of names. Expected number is 3, we got "+number_of_names);
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image: JSR233 Javascript assertion]

You can also choose Groovy in JSR223. It should be faster. Use this code (it will check length of array and if "John" is present):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json_body = jsonSlurper.parseText(SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString())
log.info("Finding JSON in response data: $json_body");
def json_names=json_body.names;
def number_of_names=json_names.size();

if(number_of_names <= 4) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
    AssertionResult.setError(true);
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Failed to match number of names. Expected number is 4, we got "+number_of_names);
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
}

if(! json_names.contains('John')) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
    AssertionResult.setError(true);
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Failed to find John in names.");
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: JSR233 Groovy assertion]

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it:

[image]

[JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) extracting into names variable:

[image]

[JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) using "names" variable:

[image]

[Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) acting on "names" variable:

[image]